# How to conect Python to MySQL installed in MAMP

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mamp

I’m a newbie with Python and I’m facing problem now I’m trying to do something with MySQL…

I want to connect Python to MySQL that I’ve installed with MAMOP (I’m a Mac user).
I run the server and playing with the pre installed phpMyAdmin everything works correctly.

I’ve installed the driver: pip3 install mysql-connector-python

Then with VS code I wrote an easy code following a tutorial:

> Blockquote

```
import mysql.connector 
conn_db = mysql.connector.connect( 
    host = "localhost", 
    user = "root", 
    password = "password" 
) 


print (conn_db)
```

> Blockquote

This is the error:
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306

Can you help me?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please replace 'password' with 'passwd'. You can refer to [Solution](https://quileswest.medium.com/using-mysql-databases-with-python-on-macos-b11a9f3c55c5)